# Accepted Answer Rate

Tags: discussion, support, accepted-answer

How can i find the percentage of accepted answer rate for each of my tags in Stack Overflow? It should list down the total number of answers provided by the user on the tag and the total number of accepted answers of the users for the tag.

Comment: SEDE has enough examples of those: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/502063/users-with-highest-accept-rate-of-their-answers

Comment: I want to view the accepted answer rate for each tags of a specific user

Comment: What does it matter?  It isn't like accepting an answer means anything to anyone but them.  Besides, we've already had the issue of users discriminating against others because their accept rate wasn't "satisfactory".

Comment: @Makoto This kinda revives the whole anti-community thing from a last week.

Answer (score 7):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/518623?UserId=100297) you go:

```
declare @userid int = ##userid:int?100297##

select t.tagname
     ,  count(*) as answers
     , sum(case when a.id = q.acceptedanswerid then 1 else 0 end) as accepts
     , sum(case when a.id = q.acceptedanswerid then 1 else 0 end) / cast(count(*) as decimal) acceptrate
from posts q 
inner join posts a on a.parentid = q.id
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = q.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where a.owneruserid = @userid
group by t.tagname
order by count(*) desc
```